# Adding GlassFish Server 4.1 to NetBeans IDE 7.4

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, netbeans-7, glassfish-4

I have installed NetBeans IDE. Also downloaded GlassFish Server and extracted it, when I'm adding the installation location on NB it says "Not a valid GlassFish Server installation."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution would be to create a new folder, select it. Click the check-box on the 'Accept License ...' and download it again within the Add Server dialog, that way it has to be where Netbeans put it.

To check why the previous download didn't work. The file it checks for should be in the following subdirectory of the directory you specify.

```
./glassfish/config/glassfish.container
```

That is if I specify `/opt/glassfish4` then `/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/config/glassfish.container` should exist.

The file should look like this:

```
#
# DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS HEADER.
#
# Copyright (c) 2010 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#
# The contents of this file are subject to the terms of either the GNU
# General Public License Version 2 only ("GPL") or the Common Development
# and Distribution License("CDDL") (collectively, the "License").  You
# may not use this file except in compliance with the License.  You can
# obtain a copy of the License at
# https://glassfish.dev.java.net/public/CDDL+GPL_1_1.html
# or packager/legal/LICENSE.txt.  See the License for the specific
# language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
#
# When distributing the software, include this License Header Notice in each
# file and include the License file at packager/legal/LICENSE.txt.
#
# GPL Classpath Exception:
# Oracle designates this particular file as subject to the "Classpath"
# exception as provided by Oracle in the GPL Version 2 section of the License
# file that accompanied this code.
#
# Modifications:
# If applicable, add the following below the License Header, with the fields
# enclosed by brackets [] replaced by your own identifying information:
# "Portions Copyright [year] [name of copyright owner]"
#
# Contributor(s):
# If you wish your version of this file to be governed by only the CDDL or
# only the GPL Version 2, indicate your decision by adding "[Contributor]
# elects to include this software in this distribution under the [CDDL or GPL
# Version 2] license."  If you don't indicate a single choice of license, a
# recipient has the option to distribute your version of this file under
# either the CDDL, the GPL Version 2 or to extend the choice of license to
# its licensees as provided above.  However, if you add GPL Version 2 code
# and therefore, elected the GPL Version 2 license, then the option applies
# only if the new code is made subject to such option by the copyright
# holder.
#
containers=jruby, web, php
jruby.application=app/controllers/application.rb
web.application=WEB-INF/web.xml
php.urlpattern=.*php$
```

**Update**

I missed the version number for your Netbeans.  For Netbeans 7.4, it looks like you need to use Glassfish 4.0 so either upgrade your Netbeans to 8.02 or download the older version of Glassfish.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm new to this, and this is a great help. Hope you can help me soon with other concerns regarding Java.